# grub unusable output after fresh elementaryOS 6 install

Tags: grub

After doing a fresh install of Odin, whole disk, on a 2015 13” MacBook Pro the grub menu is showing 1 row of pixels of output.

Seemingly, this error also prevented me from being able to use the Encrypted Disk functionality available during OS install, as I am now realizing the reason the system seemed to hang after reboot was that the prompt for the password was invisible due to this same error.

However, I then reinstalled without encryption and am now facing this grub issue. Of course, if I wait the 10 seconds it will just boot normally but I cannot choose any grub settings.

[image: grub output showing 1 row of pixel]

I tried modifying the grub file like so:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLEU=menu
GRB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="earlyprintk=vga"
```

This didn't work so I tried:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

And that didn't work so I tried:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing boot-repair and using it to disable Secure Boot, which also went ahead and reinstalled grub in the course of disabling that option. Now regular grub things/settings are working. Leaving this unanswered in case someone knows why this happened, as I still believe this is related to not being prompted for disk encryption password after installing elementaryOS with disk encryption.